# Significato di "tradire la fiducia in un rapporto"

Tags: meaning

Buongiorno,

Qualcuno mi sa spiegare cosa significa avere fiducia nel rapporto con una persona, e cosa significa tradire la fiducia in un rapporto?

Grazie.

Comment: Detta così, sembra una domanda di psicologia... :)

Answer (score 2):

"Avere fiducia in qualcuno" or "fidarsi di qualcuno": to trust somebody.

"Tradire la fiducia di qualcuno": to betray somebody's trust.

Comment: "Avere fiducia **in** qualcuno", not "di qualcuno".